# match rows of pandas df w/ another df based on cols, but ignore rows for cols based on value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I start out with two dataframes, my main dataframe with rows of data (will call it **df**), and another dataframe that i want to match the **df**'s rows to (will call it known database, or **kd**).

**df =**

```
      f    p     w
pt1   1    50    9
pt2   a    b     c
pt3   d    e     f
pt4   g    h     i
```

**kd =**

```
      f_lo    f_hi    p_lo     p_hi     w_lo    w_hi
db1   1       5       30       85       8       15
db2   0       0       0        0        0       0
db3   1       6       50       64       6       15
db4   5       0       45       70       9       18
```

Only going to look at matching **pt1** right now. The criteria for matching a row in **df** to a row in **kd** is if **(f_lo < f < f_hi) & (p_lo < p < p_hi) & (w_lo < w < w_hi)**

So here, we see that **pt1** matches to **db1** and **db3**, and for every row I append a list of these matches, so it would look like:

df =

```
      f    p     w    list_of_matches
pt1   1    50    9    [db1, db3]
pt2   a    b     c    [...]
pt3   d    e     f    [...]
pt4   g    h     i    [...]
```

I know how to do all of the above right now. However, I want to change how the above works by changing the criteria for matching based off the availability of the data in **kd**. Specifically, if any of the attributes **(f, p, w)** has an upper or lower bound equal to zero, then we skip using that attribute to match altogether, but still use the other criteria. In the case that there all the attributes contain a zero in one of their bounds (or they are all zero), then we skip matching that row of **kd** altogether. So here, we would not ever attempt to check bounds for a match for **db2** at all.

For example, since **f_hi** for **db4** is zero, I don't use the **f** attribute to match for any of the rows in **df**, and only use the other two. The criteria just for this row in **kd** becomes just **(p_lo < p < p_hi) & (w_lo < w < w_hi)** Then because we no longer use **f** as a deciding attribute, **pt1** matches with **db4** as well and we get

df =

```
      f    p     w    list_of_matches
pt1   1    50    9    [db1, db3, db4]
pt2   a    b     c    [...]
pt3   d    e     f    [...]
pt4   g    h     i    [...]
```

current code before needed fix Code. I store the list_of_matches in a dict before i append it to the df after:

```
match_dict = {}
for id, row in df.iterrows():
    seriesf = (row.f >= kd.f_lo) & (row.f <= kd.f_hi)
    seriesp = (row.p >= kd.p_lo) & (row.p <= kd.p_hi)
    seriesw = (row.w >= kd.w_lo) & (row.w <= kd.w_hi)

    final_series = seriesf & seriesp & seriesw

    list_of_matches_local = list(kd[final_series].index)
    match_dict[id] = list_of_matches_local
```

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

It took me a bit but I crafted an answer:

First I produce some sample data:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[1,50,9],[5,8,20]], index=['pt1', 'pt2'], columns=['f', 'p', 'w'])

db1 = [1,5,30,0,0,15]
db2 = [0,0,0,0,0,0]
db3 = [1,10,2,80,0,0]
names = ['flo', 'fhi', 'plo', 'phi', 'wlo','whi']
index = ['db1', 'db2', 'db3']

kd = pd.DataFrame([db1, db2, db3], columns = names, index = index)
```

A view on the sample data:

```
df

    f   p   w
pt1 1   50  9
pt2 5   8   20

kd  

   flo  fhi plo phi wlo whi
db1 1   5   30  0   0   15
db2 0   0   0   0   0   0
db3 1   10  2   80  0   0
```

Next up, I create a value checker that takes a hi a low and a value. There are three return values:
  ;10, when the value is in between the hi and low
  ;11, when the hi OR low is 0
  ;0, when the value is NOT in between the hi and low

```
def checker(lo, hi, value):
    if hi == 0 or lo == 0:
        return 11
    if value <= hi and value >= lo:
        return 10
    else : 
        return 0
```

Then I create another checker function, but this time for a whole row of values in kd. I use a sum instead of True/False in order to filter out the scenario where all the db values are zero.

```
def rowcheck(da):
    if sum(da) in [30,31,32]:
        return True
    else :
        return False
```

The biggest chunk of code is the evaluator. The function analyses al the databases for a given row index e in df. The function creates an array of arrays, with each subarray containing three value (0,10 or 11). Then each subarray is evaluated to True or False. The function ultimately returns an array with a a True/False value for each db (on a given row in df):

```
def evaluator(e):
    checkerlist = []
    for index in range(len(kd.index)):
            checkerlist.append([])
            for i, element in enumerate(df.columns):
                checkerlist[index].append("")  
                checkerlist[index][i] = checker(kd.iloc[index][element+'lo'], kd.iloc[index][element+'hi'], df.iloc[e][element])

    finalchecker = []
    for e in checkerlist:
        neu = rowcheck(e)
        finalchecker.append(neu)

    return finalchecker
```

Finally, we have to iterate through all the indices of kd to find all the valid db's for each row. Then we overlay an array of all the databases with the True/False array, created for each row by the evaluator. This will lead to a new array which will be the new column in the dataframe:

```
newcol = []
for e in range(len(df.index)):
    newcol.append([i for (i, v) in zip(list(e for e in kd.index), evaluator(e)) if v])
```

This array can then be added to the df:

```
df['list_of_matches'] = newcol
```

The final dataframe looks like this:

```
df

    f   p   w   new
pt1 1   50  9   [db1, db3]
pt2 5   8   20  [db1, db3]
```

Playing around with the db values and kd values worked out very well.

Please note that this code probably can be made slimmer and (way) faster.

Thanks for letting me know if this solution works for you!

Comment: from running your code, the solution DOES work, but i was hoping for a more pandas-vectorized answer. I for the most part already know how to do it if i were to iterate through each item. Thanks though.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  As mentioned this is indeed far from the most efficient solution. Did you run the code on all the data? Did it run within a reasonable time fame? I would also suggest to clean the kd dataframe first by setting all the 0's to NaN and then drop the rows that have only NaN's. My original idea was to create a multi-indexed dataframe with all the data, but that didn't turn out very well. I'm looking forward to a more efficient solution from you or someone else. Best, Steven.